# 'str' object has no attribute 'push_link'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I know this might seems to be a common problem, but I just can't seem to resolve this issue. Here is the code:

```
def init():
    global pushbullet_client, wanted_pokemon
    # load pushbullet key
    with open('config.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        # get list of pokemon to send notifications for
        wanted_pokemon = _str( data["notify"] ) . split(",")
        # transform to lowercase
        wanted_pokemon = [a.lower() for a in wanted_pokemon]
        # get api key
        api_key = _str( data["pushbullet"] )
        if api_key:
            pushbullet_client = api_key


# Safely parse incoming strings to unicode
def _str(s):
  return s.encode('utf-8').strip()

# Notify user for discovered Pokemon
def pokemon_found(pokemon):
    # get name
    pokename = _str(pokemon["name"]).lower()
    # check array
    if not pushbullet_client or not pokename in wanted_pokemon: return
    # notify
    print "[+] Notifier found pokemon:", pokename
    # Locate pokemon on Google Maps
    google_maps_link = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + str(pokemon["lat"]) + "," + str(pokemon["lng"]) + ',20z'
    notification_text = "Pokemon Finder found " + _str(pokemon["name"]) + "!"
    disappear_time = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(pokemon["disappear_time"]).strftime("%I:%M%p").lstrip('0'))+")"
    location_text = "Locate on Google Maps : " + google_maps_link + ". " + _str(pokemon["name"]) + "will be available until" + disappear_time + "."

    push = pushbullet_client.push_link(notification_text, google_maps_link, body=location_text)`
```

I get the 'str' object has no attribute 'push_link' error. What do I do?

Comment: It's a string... strings doesn't have a `push_link` method...

Comment: And it's a string because you did this: `pushbullet_client = api_key`.  Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call what I assume are functions for a specific class, but on a string.

```
api_key = _str( data["pushbullet"] )
if api_key:
    pushbullet_client = api_key
```

`pushbullet_client` has `api_key` assigned to it, which is a string. The default string object does not have a `push_link` attribute so it is throwing that error.

Comment: I see. How, then, would be the best way to change this.

Comment: @tay_thomp : What exactly is pushbullet_client?

Comment: I want it to be the API key which will then send the notification to my phone.

Comment: @tay_thomp : an API key cannot send notifications as it is just a string. Is this an API key for a certain API? if so do they offer a python SDK? if not, have you tried implementing your own client?

Comment: They do have a python SDK I have it in my application folder.

Comment: @tay_thomp that is an API key to connect to which API?

Comment: @tay_thomp : then you need to initialize the client for that SDK with the API key. It clearly says in the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pushbullet.py) that `Pushbullet(api_key)` is how you initialize the client.